# coding Interview about arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

```
drunk_ppl = [
    {name: 'Mark', age: 20,  alcohol_type: 'Whiskey'},
    {name: 'Jon',  age: 25,  alcohol_type: 'Rum'},
    {name: 'April',  age: 22,  alcohol_type: 'Gin'},
    {name: 'Simon',  age: 50,  alcohol_type: 'Vodka'}
];

smoker = [
    {name: 'Mark', cig_a_day: 20, brand: 'Marlboro'},
    {name: 'Jon', cig_a_day: 15, brand: 'Camel'},
    {name: 'April', cig_a_day: 12, brand: 'Newport'},
    {name: 'Simon', cig_a_day: 5, brand: 'Dunhill'}
];

var drunkard = []; //creating empty array
for(var i = 0; i < drunk_ppl.length; i++) {
    drunkard[i] = drunk_ppl[i].name;
}
```

Need help with this code snippet.

basically i want something like this:

for people in `drunk_ppl`
add person’s name in `drunkard`

from `drunkard` array take a name and use that name to find brands of cigarrette from the `smoker` array.

If no match found in smoker array, do nothing

Comment: First part seems good. What have you got so far for "from drunkard array take a name and use that name to find brands of cigarrette from the smoker array" ? Also just because I'm drunk doesn't necessarily make me a "drunkard" TYVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this snippet your can wrap it on a function and you are good to go

```
smoker.filter(x=>x.name==="Mark").forEach(x=>console.log(x.brand));
```

- first your filter smoker array by the name you want
- then you print (or add it somewhere else) the brand property of the filtered by name object

Answer (score 1):

```
drunk_ppl.map(ele=>ele.name). // return array of name from drunk_ppl
forEach(function(ele, index){  //loop through array of names
console.log(smoker.find(element=> element.name === ele).brand) /*find brands for name*/
})
```